# Alias stops working after adding another one

Tags: bash, newline, wsl-2

I am using WSL2 Ubuntu with Windows. I have an alias opening Notepad++ on Windows defined inside WSL like this:

```
alias npp="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

and it works... but as soon as I add another alias, e.g.

```
alias npp="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
alias l="ls -l"
```

I get the error - `: No such file or directory/Notepad++/notepad++.exe`. It works only when it is the last alias defined in the file.

My guess is it might have something to do with a space in the Notepad++ path but I am not really sure anymore. I tried different ways of escaping with no luck. What is happening here, what's the cause and the fix?

Comment: Where are you defining those aliases, and is there any chance you are editing the file with Notepad++?  I'm thinking it could be a line-ending problem.

Comment: **You have a CR character in your file.** The alias value you've set is actually `/mnt/c/....notepad++.exe<CR>` and that is a filename that does not exist. Edit the file with an editor that can remove the CR, or use dos2unix if included in the distro/instance you are using.

Comment: In addition, the definition of `npp` was probably the *last* line of the file, which didn't end in CRLF until you added an additional line. `bash` expects a POSIX text file: one in which *every* line is terminated with a linefeed; the CR of the CRLF pair is treated like any other character.

Comment: True that! I am editing unix system files mostly with nano however it might have happened I opened aliases file with Notepad++ once :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce *if* I edit a script with those aliases using Notepad++ and leave the line endings as "Windows".  If you want to use Notepad++ to edit your bash scripts, make sure to use *Edit* -> *EOL Conversion* -> *Unix (LF)* before saving.

After doing that, the alias script works correctly for me.